# how to fetch the fired tags in a webpage using python and selenium dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-analytics, inspect-element

I have a website on which Google Analytics code fires (through Google Tag Manager). The site has a lot of pages and I want to check if Google Analytics code fires on all pages. One way would be to open the URL, open GA debugger and check the pageview firing in the console. Since there are a lot of URLs which need to be checked, is there a way to automate this process (preferably by Python)

What I've tried so far: I've managed to get the fetch the source code of the pages and then regexing my way to find specific code snippets (of GA and GTM) You can find the code below. But the problem is this will fetch just the static code. Any pixels/codes firing after the page actually loads will not be captured.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("url")

html1 = driver.page_source

html2 = print(driver.execute_script("return 
document.documentElement.innerHTML;"))
```

I also tried using BS4 and request but nothing useful came.

Comment: I guess, you can use browser mob proxy to capture the traffic, later you can parse it to get the fired tags.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) with a selenium driver to capture all HTTP requests and responses sent while a test is running and then I loop through each checking for a request url that contains 'google-analytics'.  I then parse that request to check the event values match what I am expecting.